# Consuming .ashx files in C#

Tags: xsd

I need to consume / parse .ashx files in C#. I could create strongly typed C# class by using xsd.exe and add this to my project. But the schema of the .ashx could change at anytime.

So, I don't want to create C# classes using command line utility like xsd.

Is there  any way i can create C# class on the fly from a .ashx and use the class to parse the .ashx content?.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you need to parse/consume is the XML produced by the .ashx handler.

There is no way I know of to generate a class directly using .NET functions - you could call `xsd.exe` and then load and compile the generated code - quite a hack.